# Как отключить кнопку отправка

Tags: javascript, html

Как отключить форму отправки, но отключить только тогда, когда все поля заполнены. На полях стоит required .

```
    $(document).on('click','.best-price-popup__footer-close', validate);


    function validate(){
        let email = document.getElementById("bpp_email");
        let phone = document.getElementById("bpp_phone");
        let link = document.getElementById("bpp_link");
        let price = document.getElementById("bpp_price");
        let checkbox = document.getElementById("bpp_checkbox");

        let emailTest = /^[\w-\.]+@[\w-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i;

        if(email.value.length < 3 || emailTest.test(email.value) == false) {
            return false
        }

        if(phone.value.length < 1 ) {
            return false
        }

        if(link.value.length < 5 ) {
            return false
        }

        if(!price.value) {
            return false
        }

        if(!checkbox.checked) {
            return false
        }

        let submit = document.querySelector('.best-price-popup__footer-close')
        if(submit != null) {
            submit.disabled = true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: вы бы поподробнее описали вопрос, привели бы код формы и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Кнопку можно отключить с помощью `disabled` прописанного при создании кнопки, можно сделать проверку на заполненность полей и если все поля заполнены, то через JS убирать этот параметр. Но т.к. вы не скинули код, то ничем не могу помочь в плане JS.

Вот пример как сделать отключенную кнопку только через html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Отключенная кнопка</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Button" disabled>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: подскажите в чем может быть проблема, по вашему совету написать валидацию для формы при нажатии на submit она выполняется, если все гладко то блочик кнопку, но перестала отправлять. Хотя должна была отпрвить и заблочить. Код прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: @bazmexes, функцию отправки надо сделать внутри вашей валидации, скорее всего вы просто отключаете кнопку до отправки данных, в следствии чего она не хочет работать.